# Reading a file in an Elasticsearch plugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, accesscontrolexception

I am writing an elasticsearch plugin which relies on reading data from a file on disk. When I try to access this file in my code, I get the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "patient_similarity/codes.txt" "read")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:127)
at org.gatech.lucene.search.store.DotProductStore.<init>(DotProductStore.java:22)
at org.gatech.lucene.search.store.DotProductStore.newInstance(DotProductStore.java:71)
at org.gatech.elasticsearch.CommonsPlugin.onModule(CommonsPlugin.java:39)
```

Is there any recommended method of accessing files in elasticsearch plugins? Is there any quick workaround to access the file in my plugin?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to do this is to start the Elasticsearch process by disabling the security manager, like this:

```
 bin/elasticsearch -Dsecurity.manager.enabled=false
```

Since ES 2.x, the Java security manager is enabled by default, it was disabled earlier. Note, though, that this option will be [removed in 2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting-security.html#_disable_the_java_security_manager) because it makes your ES process vulnerable.

The correct way of doing this is to customize your [security policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting-security.html#_customising_the_classloader_whitelist) and specify the file(s) you want to access using [policy files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html#Examples):

```
grant { 
    permission java.io.FilePermission "/tmp/patient_similarity/codes.txt", "read,write";
};
```

You can add this policy in four different locations:

1. either system wide in `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.policy`
2. or for just the elasticsearch user in `/home/elasticsearch/.java.policy`
3. or from a file specified on the command line: `-Djava.security.policy=someURL`
4. or in the `plugin-security.policy` file [included in your plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/plugin-authors.html#_java_security_permissions).

Since you're developing a plugin, you should of course use option 4.

Comment: In ES 6.x docs the security manager stuff is mentioned but the details have been removed. Adding the policy file is now the only way to do this.

Comment: We are using ES version 7.x with Java 12 and we need to read and write in a directory. Please provide us the solution.

Comment: @HardikDobariya this question is closed, feel free to ask a new one by referencing this one.

Comment: @Val: Thank you. I have opened a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326513/read-and-write-files-to-a-folder-in-elastic-search-plugin

Comment: When using puppet one can implement option 3:
`elasticsearch::jvm_options: - '-Djava.security.policy=someUrl'`

Comment: @user18154574 no you don't have that level of control over the JVM on Elastic Cloud and you don't have access to the filesystem either

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my elasticsearch RestHandler plugin and I was reading the file content from some url say "http://google.com/content.json" I resolved it via below approach -

```
 `
String url = "http://google.com/content.json";
URL fileUrl = new URL(url);
InputStream is = fileUrl.openStream();
`
```