# Elasticsearch Docker container cannot Snapshot to Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, search, google-cloud-storage

This simple task is starkly difficult to debug using the resources online. Let me explain the use case, then the three lines of code that are expected to perform the task; then the errors, and the permissions conflicts that appear to be innate to the problem. Please advise.

**Use Case:**

Elasticsearch provides one of the few competitors to Google Cloud Search and Google Search. Elasticsearch is the managed service stack build on top of open-source Solr.

Elasticsearch creates backups of its index, called Snapshots. Elasticsearch manages an internal infrastructure using Google Cloud Services and its standard Service Account permissions files to create a feature for these Snapshots to be uploaded to and downloaded from a Google Storage bucket, instead of the machine running the ElasticSearch server. These internal GCS services are managed by adding a Service Account json file through the `bin/elasticsearch-keystore add-file` mechanism and registering the expectation using the `PUT _snapshot/BACKUP_NAME/` mechanism. Then, Snapshots are created or restored using a similar series of `PUT` and `GET` calls to the ElasticSearch server.

Elasticsearch conveniently hosts a Docker container so that the entire installation and launch service can be containerized: `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.2`

This tutorial describes the process, with appropriate links to official Elasticsearch pages, despite being from 2019:
https://medium.com/@KarakasP/saving-elasticsearch-backups-into-google-cloud-storage-d230ab12a7e7

The process takes four lines of code. The docker container is running on my local laptop, and my Service Account has been used for making Google Storage client calls using my own stack of Google client calls in other applications. The problem is in location appropriate documentation of the workflow from Elasticsearch necessary to launch this feature for software developers.

**Problem**

Attempting to build that workflow creates a read-permissions error `"java.security.AccessControlException","error.message":"access denied \"java.io.FilePermission\"` for a specific file, `usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config`. This file does not exist within the Docker container: however, creating this file does not resolve the error. Neither does setting the internal filesystem permissions to `chmod 1777`. The source of this error is the `java.security.FilePermission` permission structure of the Java system running Elasticsearch inside the Docker container. Strangely, very, very few forums or search results appear on Google which identify this problem or walk the user through a straightforward solution: that is the over-arching purpose of this ticket as we solve this relatively simple, ground-foundation Elasticsearch troubleshooting. A few forums from years ago mention that user control over `java.security` has been disabled from Elasticsearch 5.0 forward, which leaves me confused and at a loss for moving ahead. I suspect the problem is one or two lines of configuration file added after the Docker is launched.

**Logs**

```
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-22T17:41:34.353Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"put repository [cheese7]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[05b6814dda47][masterService#updateTask][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"034Ez40kSKiiocCGr8Gw3A","elasticsearch.node.id":"toF_prk7Thm3JYGtsBDBPw","elasticsearch.node.name":"05b6814dda47","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-22T17:41:34.464Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"failed to load default project id", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[05b6814dda47][snapshot][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"034Ez40kSKiiocCGr8Gw3A","elasticsearch.node.id":"toF_prk7Thm3JYGtsBDBPw","elasticsearch.node.name":"05b6814dda47","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"java.security.AccessControlException","error.message":"access denied (\"java.io.FilePermission\" \"/usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config\" \"read\")","error.stack_trace":"java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (\"java.io.FilePermission\" \"/usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config\" \"read\")\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:488)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1071)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:742)\n\tat java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:147)\n\tat com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:132)\n\tat com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:122)\n\tat com.google.common.io.ByteSource$AsCharSource.openStream(ByteSource.java:474)\n\tat com.google.common.io.CharSource.openBufferedStream(CharSource.java:126)\n\tat com.google.common.io.CharSource.readFirstLine(CharSource.java:316)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getActiveGoogleCloudConfig(ServiceOptions.java:396)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getGoogleCloudProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:413)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:384)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedIOException(SocketAccess.java:33)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createStorageOptions(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:196)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createClient(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:172)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.client(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.client(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:125)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.lambda$writeBlobMultipart$8(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoidIOException$0(SocketAccess.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoidIOException(SocketAccess.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlobMultipart(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:80)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlobAtomic(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:95)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1707)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$4.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:481)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:983)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-22T17:41:34.466Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"failed to load default project id fallback", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[05b6814dda47][snapshot][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"034Ez40kSKiiocCGr8Gw3A","elasticsearch.node.id":"toF_prk7Thm3JYGtsBDBPw","elasticsearch.node.name":"05b6814dda47","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"java.net.UnknownHostException","error.message":"metadata.google.internal","error.stack_trace":"java.net.UnknownHostException: metadata.google.internal\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:560)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:178)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:532)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:637)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:280)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:385)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:407)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1308)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1241)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1127)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1657)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1581)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.getDefaultProjectId(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:252)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.lambda$createStorageOptions$4(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:208)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoidIOException$0(SocketAccess.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoidIOException(SocketAccess.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createStorageOptions(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:207)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createClient(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:172)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.client(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.client(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:125)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.lambda$writeBlobMultipart$8(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoidIOException$0(SocketAccess.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoidIOException(SocketAccess.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlobMultipart(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:80)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlobAtomic(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:95)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1707)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$4.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:481)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:983)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-22T17:41:34.477Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"failed to load Application Default Credentials", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[05b6814dda47][snapshot][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"034Ez40kSKiiocCGr8Gw3A","elasticsearch.node.id":"toF_prk7Thm3JYGtsBDBPw","elasticsearch.node.name":"05b6814dda47","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"java.io.IOException","error.message":"The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.","error.stack_trace":"java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:134)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:125)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:97)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedIOException(SocketAccess.java:33)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createStorageOptions(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:220)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createClient(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:172)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.client(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.client(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:125)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.lambda$writeBlobMultipart$8(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoidIOException$0(SocketAccess.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoidIOException(SocketAccess.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlobMultipart(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:80)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlobAtomic(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:95)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1707)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$4.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:481)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:983)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
{"@timestamp":"2023-07-22T17:41:34.479Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"path: /_snapshot/cheese7, params: {repository=cheese7}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[05b6814dda47][snapshot][T#1]","log.logger":"rest.suppressed","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"034Ez40kSKiiocCGr8Gw3A","elasticsearch.node.id":"toF_prk7Thm3JYGtsBDBPw","elasticsearch.node.name":"05b6814dda47","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryVerificationException","error.message":"[cheese7] path  is not accessible on master node","error.stack_trace":"org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoryVerificationException: [cheese7] path  is not accessible on master node\nCaused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (\"java.io.FilePermission\" \"/usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config\" \"read\")\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:488)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1071)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:411)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:742)\n\tat java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:147)\n\tat com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:132)\n\tat com.google.common.io.Files$FileByteSource.openStream(Files.java:122)\n\tat com.google.common.io.ByteSource$AsCharSource.openStream(ByteSource.java:474)\n\tat com.google.common.io.CharSource.openBufferedStream(CharSource.java:126)\n\tat com.google.common.io.CharSource.readFirstLine(CharSource.java:316)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getActiveGoogleCloudConfig(ServiceOptions.java:396)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getGoogleCloudProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:413)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId(ServiceOptions.java:384)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getDefaultProject(ServiceOptions.java:356)\n\tat com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:302)\n\tat com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.<init>(StorageOptions.java:117)\n\tat com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions.<init>(StorageOptions.java:34)\n\tat com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions$Builder.build(StorageOptions.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createStorageOptions(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:235)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.createClient(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:172)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageService.client(GoogleCloudStorageService.java:112)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.client(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:125)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.lambda$writeBlobMultipart$8(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.lambda$doPrivilegedVoidIOException$0(SocketAccess.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedVoidIOException(SocketAccess.java:42)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlobMultipart(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:474)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobStore.java:264)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlob(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:80)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.writeBlobAtomic(GoogleCloudStorageBlobContainer.java:95)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.blobstore.BlobStoreRepository.startVerification(BlobStoreRepository.java:1707)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.repositories.RepositoriesService$4.doRun(RepositoriesService.java:481)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:983)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.8.2/org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:26)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)\n"}
```

I have specifically reverted to earlier attempts to provide the most detailed error logs.
There are solution attempts that I have tried that solve some of the problems, but that seem to be non-essential once the solution itself is determined. These include adding the `project id` specifically in the `PUT _snapshot/BACKUP_NAME/` call. Attempts to put the Credential Files data directly in that call, which worked for some users in the past, do not work wither. I suspect the error is a very simple permissions problem I mistook along the way.

**References**

1. This walks through the specific steps taken. The current version of Docker already installs the GCS plug-in as a standard package, though I have tried with and without installation. Strangely, instructions to restart the Elasticsearch service without restarting the Docker container are also absent, and could help the user building search.
   https://medium.com/@KarakasP/saving-elasticsearch-backups-into-google-cloud-storage-d230ab12a7e7
2. This issue discusses the same core problem; though this users is able to embed the Credential File information directly in the `PUT` request. This did not work for me, and this is a non-standard, not-secure approach.
   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/65451
3. This discusses the general problem of Java security and file reading in Elasticsearch.
   [Reading a file in an Elasticsearch plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401917/reading-a-file-in-an-elasticsearch-plugin)
4. This addresses how updated Elasticsearch 5.0+ services are not allowed to access local files. This seems to imply that the `keystore` mechanism is supposed to read the local file and integrate its contents directly into the Elasticsearch keystore. Diagnosing this confirms that the keystore is aware of the file. It may be that I made an error in this step.
   https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/69464

**My Build**

This is the docker run command:
`docker run --rm -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.8.2`

This is the sequence of client calls being made (commands are displayed in my logs):

```
INFO:elasticsearch:GET http://localhost:9200/ [status:200 request:0.002s]
INFO:__main__:Cluster connection information: {'name': '69a39f48d8da', 'cluster_name': 'docker-cluster', 'cluster_uuid': 'd4c_Vr9wQdapS99Tozhwhw', 'version': {'number': '8.8.2', 'build_flavor': 'default', 'build_type': 'docker', 'build_hash': '98e1271edf932a480e4262a471281f1ee295ce6b', 'build_date': '2023-06-26T05:16:16.196344851Z', 'build_snapshot': False, 'lucene_version': '9.6.0', 'minimum_wire_compatibility_version': '7.17.0', 'minimum_index_compatibility_version': '7.0.0'}, 'tagline': 'You Know, for Search'}
INFO:elasticsearch:GET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health [status:200 request:0.012s]
INFO:__main__:Cluster health: {'cluster_name': 'docker-cluster', 'status': 'green', 'timed_out': False, 'number_of_nodes': 1, 'number_of_data_nodes': 1, 'active_primary_shards': 0, 'active_shards': 0, 'relocating_shards': 0, 'initializing_shards': 0, 'unassigned_shards': 0, 'delayed_unassigned_shards': 0, 'number_of_pending_tasks': 0, 'number_of_in_flight_fetch': 0, 'task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis': 0, 'active_shards_percent_as_number': 100.0}
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD shell OFF: docker cp base/_db/credentials/BASENAME_REMOVED.json 69a39f48d8da:/usr/share/elasticsearch/BASENAME_REMOVED.json
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD complete: 0.033 seconds.
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD shell OFF: docker exec -t 69a39f48d8da bin/elasticsearch-keystore add-file --force gcs.client.default.credentials_file /usr/share/elasticsearch/BASENAME_REMOVED.json
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD complete: 0.753 seconds.
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD shell OFF: docker exec -t 69a39f48d8da bin/elasticsearch-plugin install repository-gcs
INFO:base.core.lightweight_utilities.process:Executing CMD complete: 0.589 seconds.
WARNING:elasticsearch:PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/cheese7 [status:500 request:0.213s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/miniconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 466, in perform_request
    raise e
  File "/Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/miniconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 427, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
  File "/Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/miniconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 291, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/Users/USERNAME_REMOVED/miniconda3/envs/ML/lib/python3.10/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 328, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, 'repository_verification_exception', '[cheese7] path  is not accessible on master node')
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the logs it looks like each line:

1. Trying to open a file related to gcloud (`/usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config`), presumably because it lacks authentication
2. Trying to get local creds possible if running on Google Cloud (`UnknownHostException: metadata.google.internal`)
3. Warning that `"The Application Default Credentials are not available` which is unsurprising given the two previous logs entries
4. Trying to open a file related to gcloud (`/usr/share/elasticsearch/.config/gcloud/active_config`), presumably because it lacks authentication

Reading the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.12/repository-gcs.html#repository-gcs-using-service-account):

> The repository must authenticate the requests it makes to the Google Cloud Storage service. It is common for Google client libraries to employ a strategy named application default credentials. However, that strategy is only partially supported by Elasticsearch. The repository operates under the Elasticsearch process, which runs with the security manager enabled. The security manager obstructs the "automatic" credential discovery when the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is used to point to a local file on disk. It can, however, retrieve the service account that is attached to the resource that is running Elasticsearch, or fall back to the default service account that Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine or App Engine provide. Alternatively, you must configure service account credentials if you are using an environment that does not support automatic credential discovery.

Putting the two together it seems ES is failing to fetch the credentials stored in the keystore, and then fails in the fallback methods as well.

I suspect the credentials haven't been loaded into the ES keystore correctly, or your backup request is not referencing them correctly.